# Be notified when a change/update happens to a jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a several lists, on different pages, that share jQuery code for allowing them to be sorted:

```
$('.sortable_list').sortable({
      placeholder: 'placeholder',
      items: '.sortable_item',
      axis: 'y',
      containment: 'parent',
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      update: function(event, ui) {
        submitForm();
      }
    });
```

I've now got a requirement to modify a radio button when one of the lists is sorted.

Rather than having to duplicate the sortable code I was hoping to be able to use `.live()` or something similar to listen for a `change` or `update` on the list, but after trying to attach it to various places I've yet to find any that work:

```
  $('.sortable_list').live('update', function() {
    console.log('hello');
  });
```

Is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried binding to "sortupdate"? Also, I think live is now deprecated in favour of on().

Comment: Yeah I saw that it had been deprecated, but I think we're using an older jQuery UI (I think)...Will try sortupdate

Comment: Corbin, sortupdate works. Did you want to make it an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried binding to "sortupdate"?

Most jQuery-plugin events are namespaced in some manner or another.